# Scraping JavaScript (ReactTable) with BeautifulSoup

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to scrape the State level information table, related to COVID-19, from the CDC website (https://www.cdc.gov/coronavirus/2019-ncov/index.html). When using BeautifulSoup I hit an error when I begin to try an extract any information from the table. Any help would be much appreciated!

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from lxml import html 

url = 'https://www.cdc.gov/coronavirus/2019-ncov/index.html'
html_content = requests.get(url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, "lxml")

gdp_table = soup.find("table", attrs={"class": "ReactTable"})
gdp_table_data = gdp_table.tbody.find_all("div")  # contains 2 rows

# Get all the headings of Lists
headings = []
for td in gdp_table_data[0].find_all("td"):
    # remove any newlines and extra spaces from left and right
    headings.append(td.b.text.replace('\n', ' ').strip())

print(headings)
```

If you are having difficulty finding the table I am referencing, it is half way down the web page, under the map of the US. Where the header reads 'States' hit the '+' next to it.

Comment: Firstly, could you please post the actual error that you are getting? The element you are trying to scrap from is a react element, it generates content only when the page is loaded. You have three options here: either use clients like selenium, hard code some js to render the elements or get the source csv like what @Dan-Dev suggests. The simplest obviously would be the third

Comment: What error, and what is your question?

Comment: Hey All! First time user, how can I post my error? Or what is best practice in posting an error. I appreciate your patience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a CSV file the web page is generated from. Just download the CSV from https://www.cdc.gov/coronavirus/2019-ncov/map-data-cases.csv

Comment: Thank you so much! I have been looking online for this all morning. I definitely stupidly missed it. How did you come across the source data? Was it referenced in the HTML and I missed it? Linked elsewhere on the CDC website? Something else? I know my colleagues will ask me. Again, thank you.

Comment: In Firefox or Chrome right click on the page, select Inspect or Inspect Element, click Network then reload the page. You will see all the requests made when the page is loaded.

Comment: You are a saint, thank you. As a learning point should probably sort out my code :).

Comment: Not me, 5 star review!

Comment: One more than @Dan-Dev. Do you you know how I can automate pulling that data from the website using python. Even if it's just a friendly nudge in the right direction. I would need to pull daily or weekly depending on the freshness of the data (which I am digging into).

Comment: Which OS do you use? On Linux (and Mac) you would set up a cron job and use wget (you can Google both). On Windows you could set up a scheduled task to run Python or PowerShell, if you use Python just use requests and write it to a file.